# VSS for layer 3 only 6500

Tags: layer3, cisco-6500, vss

I have 2 6500 at the core, that have only L3 links to the DC and the campus. I'd like to set VSS but I'm wondering if it's possible in such scenario. It uses OSPF for the routing.

I'll have the unified configuration, the NSF ans SSO technologies, ..

But the VSL is L2 only I think? So how could it work?

Comment: VSS uses the supervisor tengigabit links to create the VSL. When implemented the configuration is made by VSS and cannot be changed. Traffic will be load-balanced only if necessary and no matter if it's layer 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

VSS uses the supervisor tengigabit links to create the VSL. When implemented the configuration is made by VSS and cannot be changed. Traffic will be load-balanced only if necessary and no matter if it's layer 2 or 3.

VSS uses Interchassis stateful failover which results in no disruption to applications that rely on network state information (for example, forwarding table info, NetFlow, Network Address Translation [NAT], authentication, and authorization). VSS eliminates L2/L3 protocol reconvergence if a virtual switch member fails, resulting in deterministic subsecond virtual switch recovery.

Note that the data planes of both chassis are active and hence forward traffic at full combined capacity of 1440 Gbps.